# How to create a self relation in amplify graphql api v2

Tags: aws-amplify

I need to create categories with subcategories. One category has many categories and has many posts.

I try whit this

```
`type Category @model {
  id: ID!
  parentID: ID!
  title: String!
  parent: Category @belongsTo(fields: ["parentID"])
  children: [Category] @hasMany(indexName: "byParent", fields: ["id"]
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be something like this:

```
type Person @model {
    id: ID!
    children: [ParentsChildren] @hasMany(indexName: "byParent", fields: ["id"])
    parents: [ParentsChildren] @hasMany(indexName: "byChild", fields: ["id"])
}

type ParentsChildren @model {
    childID: ID! @index(name: "byParent")
    parentID: ID! @index(name: "byChild")
    parent: Person @belongsTo(fields: ["parentID"])
    child: Person @belongsTo(fields: ["childID"])
}
```

Comment: Hi, how many levels i can do whit this relationship?

Comment: I think it would be infinite. A child can be a parent, and can always be a child.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of v2.

```
type Category @model {

    id: ID!
    parentID: ID! @index(name: "byParent", queryField: "categoryByParent")
    children: [Category] @hasMany (indexName: "byParent", fields: ["id"]) 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add a GSI  with `@key` define the connections explicitly.

`type Category @model @key(name: "ByParent", fields: ["parentID"]) { id: ID! parentID: ID! title: String! parent: Category @connection(fields: ["parentID"]) children: [Category] @connection(keyName: "ByParent", fields: ["id"]) description: String }`

Comment: Hi, I use graphql API v2. How would it be in v2?